# How to unSubscribe Changefeeds in RethinkDB? When changes is over

Tags: java, rethinkdb

```
Cursor changeCursor = r.table("users").changes().run(conn);
for (Object change : changeCursor) {
    System.out.println(change);
}
```

I only need to know changes once.
I know "changeCursor.close()" can stop feeds. The problem is how can i know the size of the changes this time!!

If three users added, "System.out.println(change)" execute thress times.
If only one user added, "System.out.println(change)" execute one time.
Then, i need to unSubscribe Changefeeds in RethinkDB.

```
changeCursor.toList();
changeCursor.iterator();
```

Not do anythings!

```
changeCursor.hasNext();
```

Alaways true!

I don't know the number of changes. I don't know when to execute the changeCursor.close() method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking. It seems you want to instantly get the first change, then close it.

You can do something like this with javascrip driver:

```
var r      = require('rethinkdb')

r.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 28015,
})
.then(function(conn) {
  return r.table('users').changes().run(conn)
})
.then(function(cursor) {
  cursor.next()
    .then(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc)
      //Ok, now right after we get the first doc, we will close the cursor
      cursor.close()
      // if we want, we can also close connection
      // cursor.close().then(conn.close())
    })
})
```

Comment: I need to handle all changes just at the first time. Not just the first record. If three records change at one time, how can i know the changeFeeds size(3)? After handle the three record, I need to close cursor.

Comment: @李小明 No, you cannot do that unfortunately. Think of the change feed is an infinite stream, you cannot count it.

You need to design around this. Can you describe your problem and maybe we can find other solution?

Comment: I'm developing a IM system. RethinkDB is very suitable. But android not support Java8... I use Socket to feed the RethinkDB changes. When message changes,  Socket send message to android. Android send back a message to tell socket server "message received". There is only one socket work like this: receive "i'm ready" message from app > feed changes > when changes happen, handle all data in this feed (if 3 data in, handle three) and send then to app together > app send "i'm ready,i have received [message1, message2, messsage3]" back to server > server feed changes again.

Comment: while(true) { socket.getInputStream(); [handle message from app] r.table("one").filter(...).run(conn) [have offline data, send then to app, re run to socket.getInputStream(). No offline data, goon] r.table("one").changes().run(conn); [changes happen, stop feed, send changes to app] socket.getOutputStream() }

Comment: Now, i only handle first change and close feed cursor. I insert three data one time. But when app send back message, r.table("one").filter(...).run(conn) only query one data... but Two is right! And next while also query one...